# Can getstream be installed with node v8?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, getstream-io

I need to use getstream.io on firebase function. As firebase function is using the node v8, I cannot deploy the function with integration with getstream as installation of getstream requires node > v10.

Answer (score 1):

The Node.js 8.x Maintenance LTS cycle expired on December 31, 2019. That's why it's highly recommended to upgrade.

You can select node 10 with `"engines": {"node": "10"}` in your function runtime.

See details in docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_runtime_options